# How to define Angular UI-component library types that are needed by multiple modules in the library?

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-library

I'm creating a library for general purpose components used in (currently) an app. Each component will be in own module.

Now there's types that could be used by multiple / most modules like

```
export interface IUIItem {
  id: number;
  title: string;
}
```

How this should be handled? The options are:

1. Duplicate types in each module with different names like IListItem and ITableItem
2. Use common types-file for the entire library
3. ??

Option 2 sounds like more obvious thing to do because making 2-5 versions of each type is bad for multiple reasons, but then I would need to import from 2 different places to use the module.

Comment: The module you export (and therefore make publicly available) should take care of importing from whatever module it needs and export everything necessary for the "public". So having a third, shared, module is the way to go. Always treat public modules as "black-box". Nobody from the "outside" needs to know how many more modules you internally use.

Comment: @PhilippMeissner: can u pls elaborate? shared module would contain types needed by other modules and shared module is not exported outside library in public-api? then all public modules would each export the same types (if they use them) imported from the shared module? also what's the benefit of having a shared module instead of a types-file in library root folder?